# How would you count the instances of objects in arrays within an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, d3.js, meteor

So, essentially I am getting a set of records as an array of objects like

```
[{name: tyler, categories: ["friends", "neighbor"]}, {name: joe, categories: ["friends"]}].
```

and I want to count the contents of the internal array instances. So in this example, the return would be friends: 2 and neighbor: 1. As some background info, I am getting a collection of records from mongo within the meteor framework. I am then using fetch() to convert these records to an array of objects like above. I then want to use these objects to create a pie graph based on the counts of the specific instances of each object within the inner array of each object (these objects would be the ones returned by the db query) within the outer array.

Comment: You could use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest) with a rollup function.

Comment: could you expound on the rollup function? thanks!

Comment: Please correct your data declaration to put quotes around the items that are strings.

Comment: There's an example that does almost exactly what you want on [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) (linked from the documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple function to count your categories counts and store the result in a dictionary of key/value pairs.

```
function countCategories(docs){
  // accumulate results inside a JS object acting as a key/value dict
  var result = {};
  docs.forEach(function(doc){
    doc.categories.forEach(function(category){
      // initialize count to 0 when a new key is found
      if(_.isUndefined(result[category])){
        result[category] = 0;
      }
      // increment the corresponding count
      result[category]++;
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Given the sample data in your question, this function will return :

```
Object {friends: 2, neighbor: 1}
```

EDIT :

You can then convert this dictionary to an array of objects.

```
function convertToArray(dict){
  var result = [];
  _.each(dict, function(value, key){
    var object = {
      category: key,
      count: value
    };
    result.push(object);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: great this looks nice. Would it be difficult to return an array of objects like [{friends: 2}, {neighbor: 1}]?

Comment: this works great! just one more question if you dont mind. Instead of getting objects with the category as a key, would it be easy to instead get objects with a count and category name attribute. as in [{category: "friends", count: 3}, {category: "neighbors", count: 5}]. Once again thanks for the help! would it be as simple as doing something like object.categoryName = key and object.Count = value in the _.each function call?

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore and reduce:

```
result = _.reduce( data, function( counter, o ) {
    _.each( o.categories, function(c){
        counter[c] = 1 + _.result(counter, c, 0);
    });
    return counter;
}, {});
```

Demo in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/r9uaabt7/)

reduce goes through your array (first arg) and applies
the function you give it (second arg) and a starting value for
the memo (third arg).  This memo is passed to each call to
your function as the first argument, you can us it to store
stuff you want to remember.

I've set the starting value for the memo to be an empty object
which we will use as a counter.

```
result = _.reduce( data, function( counter, o ) {
    // current element of the array: o
    // stuff you want to remember for: counter
    return counter; 
}, {});
```

Comment: Does underscore have advantages over native Array functions that do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You might attach a function to the array and count the elements inside of it.

```
yourArray = [1,2,3];

yourArray.countElements = function(){ 
  var elements=0; 
  for(x=0;this[x]!=undefined;x++){ 
    instances++ 
  } 
  return instances; 
};

yourArray.countElements(); // outputs 3
```

Modify this, using "neighbors" and "friends" instead of "elements" and counting them only if this["categories"]["the_category"] is different of undefined.

Also you could attach it to Array.prototype